# Celery/Kombu worker under Docker worker won't pick up messages from SQS

Tags: docker, celery, kombu

I'm enqueuing jobs to AWS SQS from a local env and I'm able to consume them successfully from the same local env but when I try to pack the worker into a docker instance and run it, it *will not* pick up the jobs.  As far as I can tell, it is hitting the right queues, there are no errors, but it just won't consume the jobs.

## Python env

```
python --version
Python 3.9.6

pip list
amqp             5.0.7
billiard         3.6.4.0
boto3            1.20.24
botocore         1.23.24
celery           5.2.1
click            8.0.3
click-didyoumean 0.3.0
click-plugins    1.1.1
click-repl       0.2.0
jmespath         0.10.0
kombu            5.2.2
pip              21.1.3
prompt-toolkit   3.0.24
pycurl           7.44.1
python-dateutil  2.8.2
pytz             2021.3
s3transfer       0.5.0
setuptools       56.0.0
six              1.16.0
urllib3          1.26.7
vine             5.0.0
wcwidth          0.2.5
```

## requirements.txt

```
celery[sqs]
```

## local environment

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="AKIA*********"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="**********"
```

## my 'task code

```
from celery import Celery
import pprint

app = Celery('tasks')
app.conf.broker_transport = 'sqs'
app.conf.broker_transport_options = {
    'region': 'ap-southeast-2'
}
app.conf.result_backend = 'rpc://'

print("----------------------------------------------")
pprint.pprint(app.conf)
print("----------------------------------------------")

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

## consuming messages from local

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.15-alpine3.13

COPY ./app /app

WORKDIR /app

CMD ash -c "apk add --no-cache build-base libcurl curl-dev; pip3 install -r requirements.txt; celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=debug"
```

## Log of consuming messages running local (mac)

https://pastebin.com/uudPyJwu

## Log of (not) consuming messages running from docker

https://pastebin.com/giMuahKJ

## AWS console showing one message successfully consumed using local and a second message sat there doing nothing

[image: Screen Shot 2021-12-19 at 11 48 02 am]

Answer (score 0):

I have an exp using celery with queues in docker and I have met the issue you have.
I would first start from fixing your Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.15-alpine3.13
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
# FIRST install os packages.
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libcurl curl-dev
# Then perform pip install for modules.
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
# have a script that runs your application
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/entry.sh" ]
```

`entry.sh` inside app folder should looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# if any of the commands in your code fails for any reason, the entire script fails
set -o errexit
# fail exit if one of your pipe command fails
set -o pipefail
# exits if any of your variables is not set
set -o nounset

cd /app
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=debug
python3 app.py
```

Even though you have started a celery instance, you still need to run your application code (the one you specified at `my 'task code`)

Try my suggestions and feel free to comment if you still got any issues.

Comment: Hi Mark.  Thank you so much for your answer.  I have followed the instructions, I needed to make a few tweaks to get the docker container to run but alas, still not picking up jobs.  Regarding putting the ```python3 app.py``` *after* the celery -A command.... it never runs.  celery -A never stops, it just keeps polling for jobs.  If you are interested, I can share the repo with you for you can have a poke around.

Comment: @MichaelDausmann sure , I hope I'll have the time for poking. My github username is `markrity` .

Comment: Actually, don't worry Mark, I got the shits with this and rolled my own job queue implementation that works *absolutely effing fine* with docker.  it is here.   https://gist.github.com/JavascriptMick/56141fd06286b0aea7616836724d4a7c